How to use headless eclipse client to print a file in batch
I use ReqIf Studio which is basically an Eclipse client. I want to use the print functionality of Eclipse to print a file.
Why because, Reqif STudio represents REqIF file in a tabular format. I was thinking if i can use the the Print in Eclipse to export the content as pdf / html.
I would like to have it in Excel or csv but this seem to be not possible
I have like 50+ files and was thinking if I can run like headless eclipse to print to html / csv

I don't know ReqIF Studio, but if it provides such a feature then probably via the command line option -application <id> or -product <id>. So you might search the ReqIF Studio documentation for application, for product and maybe also for noSplash.
